# libxml2 errors. no such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, ios4, libxml2

I am having this problem with the libxml2 framework for at least 2 days. Even though there are plenty solutions on the web, none of them seem to work for me. This is what I have attempted so far.

1) Right click `Frameworks` and `add existing Frameworks`. Located the libxml2/libxml2.2 and added it into the Frameworks.

2) Clicked **Projects -> Edit Project Settings** and locate 2 sections: `Search Paths` and `Linking`.

3) In `Search Paths` I typed this in the following line: **Header Search Paths:** `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`

4) In `Linking` I typed this in the following line: **Other Linker Flags:** `-lxml2`

I have done all these steps as seen online. I am still getting errors. My Xcode version is 3.2.6. Do you think I have to re-install Xcode again and try again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I solved this problem already partly thanks to Jano as well.

So this is what I did.

1. Uninstalled all existing Xcode 3 SDKs
2. Reinstall MAC OS X
3. Update MAC OS X to 10.6.7
4. Install Xcode 4 in the default folder (Developer)

And it is solved! The weird experiment I tried again was to install Xcode 3.2.6 only to find the same 16 errors on the libxml2.2.dylib. So Xcode 4 works, Xcode 3 failed. Therefore, time to get use to Xcode 4!

Answer (score 11):

Header Search Paths: `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`

[image]

Other Linker Flags: `-lxml2`

[image]

Add libxml2.2.dylib in the Build Phases tab

[image]

If you did it exactly like this there may be an issue with your XCode, because that's all you need for XCode 4, 4.2 (I just tried just in case I was missing something), and if I recall correctly also for XCode 3.

Comment: what is the **TARGET NODE**?  in the `Header Search Paths:` I have tried both SDKROOT and SDK_DIR. Both did not work. `Other Linker Flags:` also did not work.

Comment: ok, now the last part I have not attempted it, will do so now!

Comment: The 3rd image you have, is a little different since its Xcode 4. And I have added the libxml2.2. Compile and still have errors. Can you explain why your libxml2.2.dylib is a white icon not a framework icon?

Comment: All dylibs look like that in XCode 4. Note that you can install XCode 4 on a different directoy and keep the v3 or target SDK 3.2 from XCode 4.

Comment: yeah, i know that. but when I do that, the interface builder will be used in Xcode 4

Comment: i have uninstalled Xcode 3.2.6 and reinstalled it hoping to see it work. But it did not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what solved this problem for me was making sure that XCode 4.0.2 is installed in the default Developer directory (hat tip to Melvin!)

I only needed to do the following:

- Uninstall XCode 3.x from the default Developer folder
- Uninstall XCode 4.0.2 from a custom folder location (it was installed at "Developer 4.0.2")
- Restart
- Install XCode 4.0.2 into the default Developer folder

I'm not certain that the restart was necessary but I threw it in for good measure.

My experience differs from Melvin's in that:

- I did not need to uninstall all of my XCode 3 SDKs (I kept XCode 3.2.5 in my "Developer 3.2.5" folder)
- I did not need to reinstall Mac OS X (I was already updated to the current version - 10.6.8 as of this writing)

Comment: interesting... It looks like Xcode 4.0.2 can't be installed in a folder other than the Default folder. Since I am using Xcode 4.0, I tried to install 4.0.2 in a separate folder and I got my libxml2 errors again. For now, I won't be attempting to fix this issue until my burden is over. Gratz James for solving this too :)