# iOS 4.2.1 and below shows images but iOS 4.3.3 doesn't

Tags: image, ios4, deployment

I have a weird problem, I have 2 testing devices running the same app and each has different outcome. Both images are loaded directly from a CMS server. The images on the devices are shown below.

iOS 4.2.1

- loads page well and image displays clearly

iOS 4.3.3

- loads page well but image displays black

I have no idea why is it like this, I am currently using Xcode 4.0.1. I have set the target build to iOS 4.0. I do wish to upgrade my Xcode, but I am afraid it will mess with what ever configs I have and I am unable to do my work. Therefore, any advice would be appreciated

*Currently images are not ready yet, I will try to make it work and update this question

**iOS 4.2.1**
[image: iOS 4.2.1]

**iOS 4.3.3**
[image: iOS 4.3.3]

Comment: You may add some code of your app to this post..

Comment: Sorry, will code affect images loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved my own problem. It could be 2 factors that are causing this problem.

1. Xcode 4.0 does not fully support iOS 4.3.3 yet.
2. The black image is too big to be supported on the 4.3.3. In the build log, I realized the byte size is 80kb more than the other one. Or maybe its the resolution, I do not know. These are just guesses for now. I have attempted to change the black image with a smaller size (both resolution and pixels) and it worked.

For now, that is what I found out about my application.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it sounds like a target issue. Are the images included in the target for iOS 4.3.3?

What kind of page are you loading?

You could install the latest and greatest XCode in a different location, so you won't mess up your current install.

[Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Comment: I actually done that before and it affected my settings. Thats why I have a little phobia on doing that. But I will try that method out. Thanks!

Comment: ok, installed the new Xcode 4.0.2. I am getting a 16 errors due to framework issue. I tried to add it or replace it, still having the same problem. I got this problem when I was using Xcode 3.2.6. Thats why I moved to Xcode 4.0, it did not give me that problem of 16errors. Now that its back, I have no idea how to resolve it except to use Xcode 4.0

Comment: There seems to be a tiny bit of image there... Am I seeing that correctly? Did you try different images, or images from a different source to rule out a problem with the image encoding?

Comment: you are not wrong, there is that tiny image. but its far from the original source. regarding the error, i have asked the question before.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424076/libxml2-errors-no-such-file-or-directory/6469313#6469313

Comment: down voted? Why? Just trying to help... 
(It may seem like a stupid question, true, but I think the question has been editted after my question. If not, then I understand.)